# How do I get Codeigniter CSRF protection to work properly with SSL?

Tags: php, codeigniter, csrf, ssl

I have CI CSRF protection turned on and it works fine with http. Once I turn on https (by changing the base URL of the site to https and redirecting all traffic from http to https) I begin to see:

`csrf token is missing on request`

errors in the logs. Codeigniter reports this error in two cases:

1) csrf token is not in POST request 
2) csrf token cookie is not set or is expired.

All our post requests (mostly AJAX) have a csrf token because our custom ajax function includes it by default, so I'm thinking it must be #2. Additionally I have played around with the config choosing both the secure and non secure cookie setting, in both cases getting this error.

My guess is that the csrf token cookie is either not set or not encrypted. My main issue is that I cannot reproduce on my own system (Chrome on Ubuntu) but once I pushed to production I saw the logs immediately flare up.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong or even how to debug a situation like this? Thanks!

Session and Cookie config:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']        = 'session';
$config['sess_expiration']         = 1209600;
$config['sess_expire_on_close']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']     = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']       = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']         = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']           = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']     = 300;


$config['cookie_prefix']    = "my";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = myconfig('use_https'); //this is true when https 
//is forced, false otherwise
```

Comment: Do you use an automatic redirection for everything? Are the links still using `http://` but you rely on a redirect to turn them into `https://`?

Comment: Nope, once I change the base url, all the links on the site become https. The redirect only happens on an initial (non-https) request. After that all the links and endpoints in the js point to https

Comment: You are not required to do "anything" to make CSRF work with SSL - the issue must lay elsewhere. I suspect your session or cookies are causing the issue. Please post all your session + cookie config.

Comment: I suspect it might have something to do with the csrf cookie not being encrypted (or not set)...

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna throw out a random answer here because you mentioned **AJAX** calls.  Something I ran into with CI CSRF protection:

http://blog.biernacki.ca/2011/12/enabling-csrf-protection-in-codeigniter-for-ajax-calls/

Because **SSL** has nothing to do with your CSRF working.  I wouldn't even assume it was that at all.  You are looking at a static call to a non HTTPS port, or not passing your token's for CSRF upon ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the user is visiting https://example.com, but the request is POSTing to https://www.example.com (or vice versa).  Try either a) setting cookie_domain to ".example.com"; or b) creating an .htaccess rule that redirects all requests for https://example.com to https://www.example.com